# Python/OpenCV: Save pictures with defined path and name

Tags: python, opencv

would like to save an image in a defined path and with a defined name.
The path is fixed, but the name from a variable.
With the name alone is no problem as you see above but how can i input the fixed path?

```
import cv2

img_name = "TEST"

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('preview',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        img_name = "{}.jpg".format(img_name)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks and best regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import cv2

img_name = "TEST"

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('preview',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        img_name = os.path.join("your_path_here", "{}.jpg".format(img_name))
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, have tried the os.path.join in the imwrite() function with error resulting ;)

Comment: @DominikTreml what do you mean?

Comment: `"your_path_here"` is a placeholder. you're supposed to change it. if you get an error, you did it wrong. please learn about relative paths and the "current working directory", and what the `os.getcwd()` of your launched python process returns

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't express myself correctly, olasimbo's solution worked, I meant that I had already tested the function in imwrite before opening this thread, but it didn't work there because I forgot the curly brackets...